# Is it OK to ask questions about BMI (Body Mass Index) here?

Tags: discussion

I have a challenge demonstrating BMI history of people in a two-dimensional diagram. I can't switch to 3D, so staying two-dimensional is very important here.

I just happened to think about StackExchange and thought maybe I can ask for help from professionals.

Is it OK to ask a question like:

How do you show a person's BMI history (like histogram) that conveys informative information about how fat or normal or underweight that person was over time?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is mainly dealing with data visualization then [SE Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable ("*...Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization*"). If you are asking about the biological interpretations of BMI the question might on-topic here (e.g. the meaning and interpretation of BMI variance and trends over time), if asked in general terms. However, note that personal medical questions and health advice are both off-topic for Biology-SE, as we cannot safely answer these.

As currently stated, I think the best fit to your question would be [SE Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).